# Java Platform SE binary has stopped working in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, runtime-error

I recently encountered an issue where I am unable to build any Apache Maven project in Netbeans. Even a simple project like Printing Hello World does not work. I tried clearing the cache, reinstalling Java, reinstalling JDK, reinstalling Netbeans, and reinstalling Apache Maven. All of this did not work. I am able to build and run the maven project via command line, but not in Netbeans. I am also able to run Ant build in Netbeans. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

I am using Netbeans 8.2, Java 8 Update 121, JDK 8 Update 121, and APache Maven 3.3.9 on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 64-bit

Let me know if there is anything else I can detail to help solve this issue

```
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.383 s
Finished at: 2017-02-07T10:16:31-05:00
Final Memory: 7M/184M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1073740791 (Exit value: -1073740791) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: I updated the question with the error from Netbeans. I forgot to include it my bad.

Comment: Hm, just a few shots in the dark: try the latest version (1.5) of the exec-maven-plugin, run as suggested Maven with the -e/-X switch to see if something useful comes up there, delete your Maven repository (usually: [UserDirectory]/.m2 but since you can compile from the command line this might be useless).

Comment: I tried updating the plugin to no success. Same error. I remade the Maven Repo and still no luck.

Comment: You said, that Maven can build your project from the console. Are you using the same Maven instance? Or the one bundled with NetBeans? You can change the used Maven instance under "Options / Java / Maven".

Comment: I am using the same one instance not the bundled one.

Comment: Someone had the same problem here: http://www.guj.com.br/t/maven-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojo-exec-maven-plugin-1-2-1/342567 (Punchline: delete 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache' and 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\var')

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Netbeans removing these folders and still no luck. I ended up re-imaging the machine solving the problem. Faster than figuring out what broke.